# How can I format date by locale in Java?

Tags: java, date, formatting, locale

I need to format date to app that has many languages, what is best way to format date, because every country has different kind of date formatting, so is it possible to format date by locale?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes, using [DateFormat.getDateInstance(int style, Locale aLocale)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) 
This displays the current date in a locale-specific way.

So, for example:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, yourLocale);
String formattedDate = df.format(yourDate);
```

See the docs for the exact meaning of the style parameter (`SHORT`, `MEDIUM`, etc)

Comment: How do you include minutes and seconds in this? This would be useful since just the day is a bit too coarse.

Edit: Nevermind, it's with `getTimeInstance()`

Answer (score 14):

SimpleDateFormat has a constructor which takes the locale, have you tried that?

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Something like
`new SimpleDateFormat("your-pattern-here", Locale.getDefault());`

Comment: Specially for i18n applications that are used from different countries, only the solution from @Bozho would work, as you don't know the "pattern" you need to use

Answer (score 2):

## Joda-Time

Using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4 library. The `DateTimeFormat` class is a factory of `DateTimeFormatter` formatters. That class offers a [`forStyle`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forStyle(java.lang.String)) method to access formatters appropriate to a `Locale`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "MM" ).withLocale( Java.util.Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
String output = formatter.print( DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ) );
```

The argument with two letters specifies a format for the date portion and the time portion. Specify a character of 'S' for short style, 'M' for medium, 'L' for long, and 'F' for full. A date or time may be ommitted by specifying a style character '-' HYPHEN.

Note that we specified both a Locale and a time zone. Some people confuse the two.

- A time zone is an offset from UTC *and* a set of rules for Daylight Saving Time and other anomalies along with their historical changes.
- A Locale is a human language such as Français, plus a country code such as Canada that represents cultural practices including formatting of date-time strings.

We need all those pieces to properly generate a string representation of a date-time value.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [java.text.DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html).
Easier to use (with a bit less power) is the derived class, [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

And here is a good intro to Java internationalization: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/index.html (the "Formatting" section addressing your problem, and more).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Laura and the SimpleDateFormat which is the best way to manage Dates in java. You can set the pattern and the locale. Plus you can have a look at this [wikipedia article about Date in the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#List_of_the_world_locations_by_date_format_in_use) -there are not so many different ways to use it; typically USA / China / rest of the world -

Comment: SDF with locale only works if you know the pattern since the locale only influences the day and month names. If you want to have a locale specific locale, you cant use it. (However the locale specific patterns are full of suprise so I dont blame anybody for using them - in fact i would always use ISO dates, no need for locales :)