# Format Date according to locale and then get the date part

Tags: java, date

What I want to achieve is to convert a date in format `yyyyMMdd` to locale format i.e `yyyy/MM/dd` or `dd/MM/yyyy` etc. 
I am not interested in the time part, I just require date.

The function would take string date and return a string date in locale format.

What I currently have is:

```
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.getDefault());
convertedDate = dateFormat.parse("20120521");
```

Everything that I have tried after that either return me a long string with time and GMT etc, or the same string that I passed to the function.

Comment: Have you tried `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(convertedDate)`?

Comment: Is the output that you are looking for some substring of what you are getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you've already got the parsing part sorted - that's *entirely* separate from the formatting part.

For formatting, I suspect you want:

```
DateFormat localeFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale);
String text = localeFormat.format(convertedDate);
```

... experiment with `SHORT`, `MEDIUM`, `LONG` and `FULL` to see which one meets your needs best, but I suspect it'll be `SHORT` or `MEDIUM`.

(You can omit the second argument to `getDateInstance` and it will use the default locale, but personally I'd advise including it explicitly for clarity.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the DateFormat built in types

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.Short, Locale.getDefault()));
```

As per the Javadocs

> Use getDateInstance to get the normal date format for that country.
>   There are other static factory methods available. Use getTimeInstance
>   to get the time format for that country. Use getDateTimeInstance to
>   get a date and time format. You can pass in different options to these
>   factory methods to control the length of the result; from SHORT to
>   MEDIUM to LONG to FULL. The exact result depends on the locale, but
>   generally:
>
> SHORT is completely numeric, such as 12.13.52 or 3:30pm MEDIUM is
>   longer, such as Jan 12, 1952 LONG is longer, such as January 12, 1952
>   or 3:30:32pm FULL is pretty completely specified, such as Tuesday,
>   April 12, 1952 AD or 3:30:42pm PST.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to your question:
[How can I format date by locale in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951849/how-can-i-format-date-by-locale-in-java)

an example:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, yourLocale);
String formattedDate = df.format(yourDate);
```

Also if you have to do a lot with Dates, consider using Joda:
[Java, getting Date without time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050170/java-getting-date-without-time)

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A sample date string
        String strDate = "20210630";

        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDate, dtfInput);

        System.out.println(date.format(getShortDateFormatterForLocale(Locale.getDefault())));
        System.out.println(date.format(getShortDateFormatterForLocale(Locale.GERMANY)));
        System.out.println(date.format(getShortDateFormatterForLocale(Locale.US)));
    }

    static DateTimeFormatter getShortDateFormatterForLocale(Locale locale) {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).localizedBy(locale);
    }
}
```

**Output on my system in the UK:**

```
30/06/2021
30.06.21
6/30/21
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/NiCYbw)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>