# Partial date format in different locales

Tags: java, android, internationalization, date-format

I wanted to have my app display

```
September 2014
```

in English locale and

```
2014年9月
```

in Chinese locale.

Are there any way in Java (especially, Java 1.6 in Android) can do this?

I am interesting in the "natural" way to display the year and the month in a specific culture. So English and Chinese cultures are just an example, and the solution shall work for all system supported cultures.

For the example above, if I have something like `9月 2014` I am sure every Chinese speaker will know what it means but it is just looked very odd in that culture. On the other hand, `2014年九月` is acceptable.

**Attempts**

1. The pattern for `SimpleDateFormat` need you to specify the order of year and month field. Since this is vary in different languages this is not going to solve it.
2. If you try to bend the rule to allow displaying `2014, September` for English and `2014年, 9月` for Chinese (this is acceptable, but `2014, 9月` is still odd) and consider `Calendar.getDisplayName`, unfortunately it returns null for `Calendar.Year`.

Comment: Do you need a solution for any locale, or are you just looking for a solution for English and Chinese?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format date by locale in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951849/how-can-i-format-date-by-locale-in-java). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1661325/642706).

Comment: Tip: [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that help, but it's not tested under android:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        Date d = sdf.parse("01.09.2014");

        // get the formatter for a specific country/language
        sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(
                DateFormat.LONG, Locale.CHINESE);

        System.out.println(sdf.toLocalizedPattern());
        System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```