# How to format a date by any locale obtained from language tag with java time?

Tags: java, date, time, java-8, java-time

I want to get a date as string and a language tag and based on that to parse the string by the locale format.

This is what I've done so far:

```
public static String formatDateByLocale(String date, String languageTag) {
    Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(languageTag);
    String datePattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.LONG, FormatStyle.LONG, Chronology.ofLocale(locale), locale);

    DateTimeFormatter targetFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern).withLocale(locale);
    DateTimeFormatter currentFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");

    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, currentFormat);

    String result = targetFormat.format(localDateTime);


    return result;
}
```

This throws `Unable to extract value: class java.time.LocalDateTime`

How should I approach this to have this date: 17/04/2017 10:50AM with FR tag transform into 2017/04/17 10:50AM?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951875/4280359

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz, that answer is not concerned with `java.time`.

Comment: That's true. And the OP's method takes only strings as arguments. The question itself does not have much to do with concrete implementation using only classes from `java.time`.

Comment: Does your input data String actually fit the French localized format expected by your formatter?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Still I warmly recommend a pure `java.time` implementation when that’s available to the OP. Using the outdated classes `DateFormat` and `Date` (as in the linked answer) is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Your example is incomplete and incorrect. You should provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your example output of `17/04/2017 10:50AM` is not at all close to the actual output of French with [format style `LONG`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#LONG). So we cannot answer precisely. But here is something to point you in the right direction.

You cannot count on being able to parse any date-time input string. Some ambiguities are impossible to resolve. And some crucial information such as offset-from-UTC or time zone may be omitted. Instead:

- Within your app, pass around java.time objects, rather than mere strings.
- Between apps/systems, pass strings is standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Do so in UTC for date-time values, generally speaking.

Here is some example code showing your desired French output.

Capture the current moment in UTC as an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now( );
```

Adjust into a particular time zone. Remember that time zone has *nothing* to do with localization issues.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Determine a `Locale`. Here we use French language with cultural norms of France.

```
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag( "fr-FR" );
```

Your Question shows swapping of [`Chronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/chrono/Chronology.html) where appropriate for a locale. Has no effect here as both `Instant` and France use [`IsoChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/chrono/IsoChronology.html).

```
Chronology c = Chronology.ofLocale( locale );
```

Define a formatter. No need for the builder pattern seen in the Question.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale ).withChronology( c ) ;
```

Generate output.

```
String s = zdt.format( f );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "instant.toString(): " + instant + " at zone: " + z + " in chrono: " + c + " = " + s );
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-11-23T04:30:45.091424Z at zone: Asia/Kolkata in chrono: ISO = 23/11/2017 10:00

Note how **this output *cannot* be parsed back into a date-time value** as it lacks crucial information.

You could, in this case, parse the string to a `LocalDateTime` as shown in your Question. But you have data loss here. A `LocalDateTime` purposely has no concept of offset or zone, and so it does *not* represent a point on the timeline. A `LocalDateTime` is *not* an actual moment, only a vague hint of a range of possible moments that may be occurring over a period of about 26-27 hours. You are not even close to ending up where you started.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( s , f );
System.out.println( "ldt: " + ldt );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2017-11-23T10:00

By the way, I suggest your method take a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) rather than a mere string of the language tag. The calling programmer should be responsible for determining the full `Locale` for a valid language tag. Language tags and their variants are complicated business. The calling programmer should verify they have properly defined a valid language construct by successfully instantiating a `Locale` (and, ideally, testing it). The method at hand here should focus on date-time issues and not have to also deal with language tag complications.

Comment: Your statement about `Chronology.of(Locale)` having no effect in case of `Instant` or French locale is not true. For example: "fr-FR-u-ca-buddhist" would produce the ThaiBuddhist calendar in French language.

Comment: @MenoHochschild No, I did not say that about Chronology. I said that about time zone.

Comment: Okay, my English is of course not on your level. Anyway, I get the feeling that you care too much about timezones regarding the fact that the OP handles zoneless inputs which can be perfectly parsed to `LocalDateTime`. And I guess the real problem of OP is somewhere else - maybe related to mismatch of format pattern and/or AM/PM-support in the realm of i18n.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Actually, I do not believe we know exactly what the OP wants or what the OP is doing. The Question is unclear, mixing parsing of strings with generating strings. I get the feeling the root question here is "How do I parse any date-time string in any format?", which of course is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

#### Proposed solution

Replace your `datePattern` with `"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a"`:

```
DateTimeFormatter targetFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a").withLocale(locale);
```

Comment: That's hardcoded format. In Europe, for instance, we use dd/MM/yyyy.